# Order of lambda expressions causes Failure: Unknown parameter. Parameter name: parameterExpression Actual value was pcount

Tags: vb.net, lambda, telerik, telerik-open-access

I am getting an error when I simply flip the Skip/Take and the Order By in the select statement and cannot see how to resolve this.

The offending statement:

```
DBContext.Symbols.OrderBy(Function(obj) obj.Identifier).Skip((StartRec - 1) * EndRec).Take(EndRec).Select(Function(obj) New With {.Id = obj.Id, .Name = obj.Name, .Sector = obj.Sector, .Identifier = obj.Identifier, .isRequest = obj.isRequest, .Direction = obj.Direction, .PlanCount = obj.Plans.Count, .RequestCount = obj.UserSymbols.Where(Function(pcount) pcount.isRequest = 0).Count})
```

But if I reverse the order it works:

```
DBContext.Symbols.Skip((StartRec - 1) * EndRec).Take(EndRec).OrderBy(Function(obj) obj.Identifier).Select(Function(obj) New With {.Id = obj.Id, .Name = obj.Name, .Sector = obj.Sector, .Identifier = obj.Identifier, .isRequest = obj.isRequest, .Direction = obj.Direction, .PlanCount = obj.Plans.Count, .RequestCount = obj.UserSymbols.Where(Function(pcount) pcount.isRequest = 0).Count})
```

But this will result in me ordering the returned values that are skipped, rather than sorting them first.

> An exception occurred during the execution of 'Extent().OrderBy(obj => obj.Direction).Skip(0).Take(10).Select(obj => new VB$AnonymousType_0`8(Id = obj.Id, Name = obj.Name, Sector = obj.Sector, Identifier = obj.Identifier, isRequest = obj.isRequest, Direction = obj.Direction, PlanCount = obj.Plans.Count, RequestCount = Convert(obj.UserSymbols).Where(pcount => (pcount.isRequest == 0)).Count()))'. Failure: Unknown parameter. Parameter name: parameterExpression Actual value was pcount. See InnerException for more details. Complete Expression: .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Take( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Skip( .Call System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy( .Constant(Extent()), '(.Lambda #Lambda1)), 0), 10), '(.Lambda #Lambda2)) .Lambda #Lambda1(Symbol $obj) { $obj.Direction } .Lambda #Lambda2(Symbol $obj) { .New VB$AnonymousType_0`8[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]( $obj.Id, $obj.Name, $obj.Sector, $obj.Identifier, $obj.isRequest, $obj.Direction, ($obj.Plans).Count, .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Where( (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UserSymbol])$obj.UserSymbols, .Lambda #Lambda3))) } .Lambda #Lambda3(UserSymbol $pcount) { $pcount.isRequest == 0 }

I understand that it is stumbling on the lambda statement resolving the RequestCount and have tried moving it to a property on the object but it still reports the error.  What confuses me, is I believe it is unable to resolve UserSymbol, but I am not sure why.  I suspect it loses the object reference to properly cast the object type although not sure why.

any help is appreciated.

----Update:
I tried changing the format to use the following:

```
From obj In DBContext.Symbols Order By obj.Identifier Skip ((StartRec - 1) * EndRec) Take EndRec Select New With {.Id = obj.Id, .Name = obj.Name, .Sector = obj.Sector, .Identifier = obj.Identifier, .isRequest = obj.isRequest, .Direction = obj.Direction, .PlanCount = obj.Plans.Count, .RequestCount = obj.UserSymbols.Where(Function(pcount) pcount.isRequest = 0).Count}
```

---Update 2: Inner Excepetion

> Unknown parameter. 
>   Parameter name: parameterExpression 
>   Actual value was pcount.

Comment: Does the InnerException help at all?

Comment: I provided it above but it is not helping me. I am thinking it may be resolving to a list object if Order By returns something different than Take but that doesn't make sense imo.